# How can I set default selects in multiple select with foreach binding

Tags: knockout.js

Hello I'm trying to make default selected  multiple binding in for loop
I have following situation. 
company have  productList and managerList 
each  manager has their own  prefered_products with in company's product list. 
I want to  show this data in table. I want to make show prefered_product of manager and other products of company
html file

```
 <tbody data-bind="foreach: Managers">
  <tr >       
    <td class="col-xs-2">
         <select type="text" data-bind="options:$parent.productList,optionsText:'name', selectedOptions:prefered_products'" class="form-control" ></select>
     </td> 
 </tr>
```

js file

```
var products = [ {name: 'product1', _id : 'abc'},{name: 'product2', _id : 'def'},{name: 'product3', _id : 'ghi'}]
var managers = [ {_id : 'mand', name: 'kate', prefered_products: [{name: 'product2', _id : 'def'},{name: 'product3', _id : 'ghi'}] },
                 {_id : 'todhm', name: 'jordan', prefered_products :[{name: 'product1', _id : 'abc'},{name: 'product2', _id : 'def'}]}]
var ManagerData =function(data){
    var self = this
    self.id = ko.observable(data._id);
    self.name = ko.observable(data.name);
    self.prefered_products = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.add_product = function(product){
            self.prefered_products.push(new Product(product));
    }
    for(i=0; i< data.prefered_products.length;i++){
        self.add_product(data.prefered_products[i]);
    }
}
var ProductType = function(data){
    var self = this;
    self.name = ko.observable(data.name);
    self._id = ko.observable(data._id);
}
var ViewModel = function(){
   self.productList = ko.observableArray([]);
   self.managerList = ko.observableArray([]);
}
var ViewModel = new ViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(ViewModel);
products.forEach(function(product,index){
                       ViewModel.productList.push(new Product(product));
                   });
managers.forEach(function(manager,indexdo){
                      ViewModel.ManagerList.push(new ManagerData(manager));
                                 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your snippet contained many errors, so I took away the parts that didn't run.

The most important thing you should know, is that your `product` objects in the `manager` data are *different references* than the ones in your `products` array.

You'll need to compare them using `product1._id === product2._id`, **not** using `product1 === product2`.

For example:

```js
var products = [ {name: 'product1', _id : 'abc'},{name: 'product2', _id : 'def'},{name: 'product3', _id : 'ghi'}]
var managers = [ {_id : 'mand', name: 'kate', prefered_products: [{name: 'product2', _id : 'def'},{name: 'product3', _id : 'ghi'}] },
                 {_id : 'todhm', name: 'jordan', prefered_products :[{name: 'product1', _id : 'abc'},{name: 'product2', _id : 'def'}]}]

var Manager = function(data) {
  this.name = data.name;
  
  this.preferedIds = {};
  
  data.prefered_products.forEach(
    function(prod) { this.preferedIds[prod._id] = true; },
    this
  )
};

Manager.from = function(data) { return new Manager(data); };

var App = function() {
  this.managers = managers.map(Manager.from);
  this.products = products;

  // For one manager
  this.selectedManager = ko.observable(null);
  
  // For multiple managers
  this.selectedManagers = ko.observable([]);
  
  this.selectedProducts = ko.observableArray([]);
  
  this.selectedManager.subscribe(function(manager) {
  
    // Set the selectedProducts to the ones whose ids are
    // in the manager's prefered ids
    this.selectedProducts(
      App.productsInIdSet(products, manager.preferedIds)
    );
  }, this);
  
  this.selectedManagers.subscribe(function(selectedManagers) {
    var allIds = selectedManagers.reduce(function(all, manager) {
      return Object.assign(all, manager.preferedIds);
    }, {});
    
    this.selectedProducts(
      App.productsInIdSet(products, allIds)
    );
    
  }, this);

};

App.productsInIdSet = function(products, idSet) {
  return products.filter(function(product) {
    return idSet[product._id];
  });
}



ko.applyBindings(new App());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

<h2>For one manager</h2>

<select data-bind="options: managers, 
                   optionsText: 'name', 
                   value: selectedManager"></select>
                   
<select data-bind="options: products,
                   optionsText: 'name',
                   selectedOptions: selectedProducts" multiple></select>
                   
<h2>For multiple managers</h2>
<em>Note that from a user-experience point of view, it's very annoying that this clears any custom selections when the manager selection changes.</em>

<select data-bind="options: managers, 
                   optionsText: 'name', 
                   selectedOptions: selectedManagers" multiple></select>
                   
<select data-bind="options: products,
                   optionsText: 'name',
                   selectedOptions: selectedProducts" multiple></select>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help is their any way that I can express 2 manager at a same time?

Comment: I added an example for two `multiple` select boxes to my snippet. Note that whenever you change the manager selection, the product selection gets reset.

Comment: Thanks a lot . Sorry for not clarifying question at the first time but I tried to make a table where 2 manager data and 2 products options(total 6 products) and their preferences  are shown at the same time. In this case I want to express 
kate| product1product2product3 jordan|product1product2product3 at the same time using foreach binding.